# cin for an unknown amount of objects?

Tags: c++, queue, cin

for a project i have to make a queue that cins names of people, the number of services they want, and a list of each service they want. the same service can be asked for more than once.

basically it the input will look like this.

```
Dave 3 spa sauna pedicure
sarah 4 spa spa walk sauna
jim 1 walk
.
```

the "." denotes the end of all my inputs. no matter when walk is called, once they walk they no longer want to do anything else and leave. so in sarah's case, she goes to the spa 2 times, then walks and leaves. she doesn't get to her sauna.

my problem is i have no clue how i would actually cin the info. i assume i have a class that denotes the people but i dont know how to make it so that they can place a random amount of people. if it was just 3 people, i would use a for loop and save each one to a different spot in the array.

is there some way to simply do this?

Comment: You could kill the number of services part, use `getline` to input each line, extract the name, and use a container's two iterators constructor to initialize it with the services they need. The number can then be accessed with `size()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the special symbol to end user's input so you can ask for input until you get this symbol ("."). The code can be like this:

```
while(true)
{
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;

    if(name == ".")
        break;

    // number of services
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    // list of services
    std::vector<std::string> services(n);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cin >> services[i];

    // Here you can process user
    // You know user's name and have std::vector of his services
}
```

This code loops infinitly until user's name equals ".".

If you are going to output all your users or process them in list you have to store them in vector.

```
struct User
{
    User(const std::string& _name):
        name(_name)
    {
    }

    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> services;
};

std::vector<User> users;

int main( )
{
    std::vector<User> users;

    while(true)
    {
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        if(name == ".")
            break;

        users.push_back(User(name));

        size_t n = 0;
        std::cin >> n;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            std::string serviceName;
            std::cin >> serviceName;

            users.back().services.push_back(serviceName);
        }
    }

    for(size_t n = users.size(), i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << users[i].name;
        std::cout << " ";
        std::cout << users[i].services.size();
        std::cout << " ";
        for(size_t s = users[i].services.size(), j = 0; j < s; ++j)
            std::cout << users[i].services[j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code reads users and their services then prints them back.

There can be another way to read each user if you know that each user is on separate line.

```
std::string l;
std::getline(std::cin, l);

std::istringstream ss(l);

std::string name;
ss >> name;
if(name == ".")
    break;

users.push_back(User(name));

size_t n = 0;
ss >> n;

for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::string serviceName;
    ss >> serviceName;

    users.back().services.push_back(serviceName);
}
```

I am reading the whole line from input stream (cin), then create stringstream (ss) and read user info from it.

Comment: thank you. i wasn't sure exactly how i was going to process the input but this seems like they way im going to do it. i didnt know exactly how to show each cut off but this works well.

Comment: @T.J.Williams Welcome to SO. If this solved your problem you should accept the answer. If it was some still useful, you should upvote. Use the buttons on the left of the answer panel.

Answer (score 0):

read in the name, once they enter the number of actions they will perform loop through that number. create a constant char to represent each of the possible locations(from what i understand there are specified places they can visit). If the next read is walk then end the loop. Here is a really rough outline of your code(given my understanding), this was done in a hurry to check for any errors of mine

```
    Declare consts ex:
        const string SPA = "spa";
        const string PEDICURE = "pedicure";
        //etc..etc..

    Decalre vars ex:
        int actions; //amount of actions
        //etc...e

tc..
WHILE name is not the dot

    prompt user for name
    read in name

    prompt user for amount of actions
    read in actions

    DO THIS
        prompt user for action
        read in action into string

        convert to lowercase(optional)
        compare action to possible places
            increment chosen place
        increment counter var(s)
    WHILE input is not walk and actions does not exceed max actions


display output
```

Answer (score 0):

For `getline` is easy:

```
string line;
while(getline(cin,line))
{
    if (line.empty())
       break;
    file.push_back(line);
}
```

But to `cin objects`, **I found a way to break at the end, without the need for any breaking character**. You have to use the same variable to cin all of the objects. After usage, you need to set it to a default exit value. Then check if your variable is the same after the next cin. Example:

```
string o;
while(true){
    cin>>o;
    if (o.compare("tmp")==0)
        break;
    // your normal code
    o="tmp";
}
```